# How do I continue a python program after a while loop exits?

Tags: python

I have a python3 program that guesses the last name of an individual based on the input of the user. But I figured out how to break if the user answer now, but when the user says yes it just re-enter the loop again with the same initial question.

```
while True:
    answer = input('Do you want me to guess your name? yes/no :')
    if answer.lower() == 'no':
        print("Great")
    else:
        time.sleep(2)
        exit('Shame, thank you for playing')

lastname = input('Please tell me the first letter in your surname?').lower()
time.sleep(2)
```

DEMO - If the user answer 'yes'

```
Do you want me to guess your name? yes/no :
Great
Do you want me to guess your name? yes/no :
Great
Do you want me to guess your name? yes/no :
```

etc.

So basically I want the program to exit on no, but continue on yes with the next question which is "Please tell me the first letter in your surname?"

Any idea?

I through after picking up some suggestion here, that I could use a while loop, but as the question stands, I did not get it right.

Please answer in a not so technical way, as my knowledge of python is very limited, still trying to learn.

Comment: Don't use `exit` use `break` in this case, or change the condition of your `while` loop

Comment: you should avoid while True ... either use break instead of exit or, better, initialize 'answer' to whatever value and use it as a condition to exit your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood the problem at first. You actually need to break the **`while`** loop when the user says Yes, so you can proceed to the 2nd question. And using an **`exit`** is fine when he says No, just remember that it will exit the ***whole program***, so if you want to do something else after he says no, it might be better to use `return` and put them into functions.

Your code should be more or less like this:

```
import time
while True:
    answer = input('Do you want me to guess your name? yes/no :')
    if answer.lower() == 'yes':
        print("Great")
        break    # This will break the actual loop, so it can pass to next one.
    elif answer.lower() == 'no':
        # I recommend printing before so if it's running on a terminal
        # it doesn't close instantly.
        print('Shame, thank you for playing')
        time.sleep(2)
        exit()
    # I suggest adding this else because users don't always write what we ask :P
    else:
        print('ERROR: Please insert a valid command.')
        pass    # this will make it loop again, until he gives a valid answer.

while True:
    # code of your next question :P repeat proccess.
```

Feel free to ask any question you have about the code :)

Comment: What prevented you from running the elif statement? Maybe you didn't **`import time`** before?

Comment: It did just the same as it did initially, but with the else print pass statement it loops as you said till the answer is true. Well and dandy, and I can use this in other quiz type of games, but what if I wanted the game to exit?

Comment: If you wanted the game to exit, that's exactly what the **`elif`** statement does. If the answer is "**no**" it will print *"Shame, thank you for playing"*, wait 2 seconds, and then exit the program. That's why I wondered why it "worked only if you removed the elif statement". What happens if you keep it or why does it malfunction?

Answer (score 0):

As CoryKramer in the comments pointed out, use break instead of exit. Exit is a python function that exits the process as a whole and thus it shuts down the interpreter itself.

Break will close the closest loop it belongs to. Thus if you have two while loops, one written inside the other. A break will only close the inner while loop.

In general your code will go something like this

```
while True:
    answer = input('Do you want me to guess your name? yes/no :')
    if answer.lower() == 'yes':
        print("Great")
        lastname = input('Please tell me the first letter in your surname?').lower()
        time.sleep(2)
    else:
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Thank you for playing!")
        break
```

This will keep looping as long as the user keeps entering yes.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to you an infinite while loop you need to control your loop state. Also i created a SurnameFunc. Using seperate functions is more readable for big projects.

```
def SurnameFunc():
  return "Test Surname ..."

State= 0
lastname_tip = ""
while(True):
  if(State== 0):
    answer = input('Do you want me to guess your name? yes/no :')
    if(answer == 'no') :
      print ("You pressed No ! - Terminating Program ...")
      break
    else:
      State = 1
  elif(State == 1):
    lastname_tip = input('Please tell me the first letter in your surname?').lower()
    State = 2
  elif(State == 2):
    print ("Your Surname is ..." + SurnameFunc())
    State = 0


print ("Program Terminated !")
```

Comment: Think this can work for a quiz type of game, but what does state do?